# Can we add the address subtab on a custom record type?

Tags: netsuite

I need to add a sub tab to my custom record which contains an address sub tab. How can I get it done?

Do we need to deploy any scripts for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can not add any standard address tab on custom record but you need to add another child custom record and you have to do parent-child relation between both record so child record will be displayed sub tab.